# length of an index after resampling in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 5 lists, `i0, i1, i2, i3` and `i4` of equal length and the data of each one came from a specific weekday. So for example `i0's` data comes from mondays data, `i1` contains data that comes from tuesdays, etc.
Now I am adding an index to each list based on the weekly day because then I'm going to add these new "small" dataframes (`x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4` and `x5`) to a bigger dataframe "`df`".

I'm doing this the following way:

```
listweek = ['W-MON','W-TUE','W-WED','W-THU','W-FRI']

for u,v in enumerate(listweek):    
        r = "x{0} = pd.DataFrame(i[{0}]).set_index(df.resample('{1}').index)".format(u,v)    
        exec r
```

The problem arises because when doing `df.resample('{1}').index`, as this sometimes has different lenghts. 
For example

`len(df.resample('W-MON').index) = 886` and

`len(df.resample('W-TUE').index) = 885`,

so this causes the code to break with the following error:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 886 elements, new values have 885 elements
```

What should be the right way of doing this?

(Adding snippet of original df)

[image]

Comment: `for u,v in [(u,v) for u,v in zip(range(5),listweek)]` ? What's wrong with `for u,v in enumerate(listweek)` ?

Comment: thats fine too, but still won't solve the issue.

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment and not as an answer ;) P.S. It's not "fine too", it's the correct way of doing your loop enumeration.

Comment: @LeartS you are right. just edited. thanks.

Comment: I think you should rethink your strategy from the ground up. Don't use Python to build a text string containing a python commands. Can't you just make the data frame and then name the columns?

Comment: Can you print a snippet of `df` before the loop?

Comment: @BobBaxley just added it. I'm calculating the variance ratio t-statistic for each day of the week on a rolling basis (that is each "i") but then need to add it back to this original df.